# How can I get the name / details of an Action delegate invocation?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm testing the performance of some similar method calls that I'm wrapping in some timing and logging statements.  I'm passing these methods in via an [Action delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) parameter.

Is there any way to print details about the call?

For example:

```
var httpResult = TestService(() => serviceHttp.Search(criteria));
var tcpResult = TestService(() => serviceTcp.Search(criteria));
var localResult = TestService(() => servicelocal.Search(criteria));

...

private static double TestService(Action serviceOperation)
{
    const int iterations = 15;
    ...

    for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        ...

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} ElapsedMilliseconds={1}", ????, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
         // Ideally this would print something like "serviceTcp.DoStuff(...) ElapsedMilliseconds=313"
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I know if you treat it as an Expression object, you can pull out some info.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression

Comment: Hmm.. You will need to change the type of serviceOperation. It's not possible to convert an Action (delegate) into an Expression tree.

Comment: Clearly you'll want to at least use an `Action<string>` delegate here, now it is simple to have the caller provide context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your testing method declaration to

```
private static double TestService(Expression<Action> expression)
```

Call `Compile` method of expression object to get a method for testing:

```
var serviceOperation = expression.Compile();
```

`Expression` object can provide a lot of information about method call, you can start with something like this:

```
private static string GetMethodCallDescription(Expression<Action> expression)
{
    var mce = (MethodCallExpression)expression.Body;
    var method = mce.Method;
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(method.DeclaringType.Name);
    sb.Append(".");
    sb.Append(method.Name);
    sb.Append("(");
    bool firstarg = true;
    foreach(var arg in mce.Arguments)
    {
        if(!firstarg)
        {
            sb.Append(", ");
        }
        else
        {
            firstarg = false;
        }
        sb.Append(arg.ToString());
    }
    sb.Append(")");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it without using expression trees; just change the signature of TestService to take the action and the parameter separately, and use the `Delegate.Target` and `Delegate.Method` properties to get the type and method:

```
var httpResult = TestService(serviceHttp.Search, criteria);
var tcpResult = TestService(serviceTcp.Search, criteria);
var localResult = TestService(servicelocal.Search, criteria);

...

private static double TestService<T>(Action<T> serviceOperation, T parameter)
{
    const int iterations = 15;
    ...

    for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        ...

        string typeName = serviceOperation.Method.IsStatic
                          ? serviceOperation.Method.DeclaringType.Name
                          : serviceOperation.Target.GetType().Name;
        string methodName = serviceOperation.Method.Name;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}.{1} ElapsedMilliseconds={2}", typeName, methodName, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
         // Ideally this would print something like "serviceTcp.DoStuff(...) ElapsedMilliseconds=313"
    }

    ...
}
```